# Query and display aggregate list

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, pageblock

I have an aggregated list that counts the number of records from a custom object created by a user that I display on a visualforce page. I need to also display the same thing from a different custom object and display it in the same pageblock. 
Here is the controller code:

```
    public List<AggregateResult> top6Contributors1
{
    get
    {
        if (top6Contributors1 == null)
        {
            top6Contributors1 = [
                SELECT CreatedById, CreatedBy.Name name,
                    count(Id) contributions
                FROM Idea_Lobby__c
                GROUP BY CreatedById, CreatedBy.Name
                ORDER BY count(CreatedById) desc limit 6
            ];
        }


        return top6Contributors1;

    }
    private set;
}
```

Here is the vf code:

```
  <apex:pageBlock >
      <apex:repeat value="{!Top6Contributors1}" var="r">

      <div class="top-con"> 
      <img src="{!$Resource.Small_Icon}" alt="ideacenter" id="person1"/>
           <ul>
              <li><span id="Name"><h4>{!r['name']}</h4></span></li>
              <li>
                  <label>Ideas</label>
                  :<span id="ideas"> {!r['contributions']}</span></li>
              <li>
                   <label>Comments</label>
                  :<span id="votes"> </span></li>

           </ul>
     </div> 

     </apex:repeat> 
     </apex:pageBlock>
```

How would I display them both?

Answer (score 1):

Could you try adding this to your controller ?

```
public List<ContributionWrapper> getContributionsWrapper(){

    List<ContributionWrapper> lContributions = new List<ContributionWrapper>();

    for(AggregateResult aResult : top6Contributors1){
        lContributions.add(aResult);
    }

    return lContributions ;
}

public class ContributionWrapper{
    public String name {get;set;}
    public Integer contributions {get;set;}

    public ContributionWrapper(AggregateResult theResult){
        name = (String) theResult.get('name');
        contributions = (Integer) theResult.get('contributions');
    }
}
```

And then update your VF page with :

```
  <apex:pageBlock >
      <apex:repeat value="{!contributionsWrapper}" var="r">

      <div class="top-con"> 
      <img src="{!$Resource.Small_Icon}" alt="ideacenter" id="person1"/>
           <ul>
              <li><span id="Name"><h4>{!r.name}</h4></span></li>
              <li>
                  <label>Ideas</label>
                  :<span id="ideas"> {!r.contributions}</span></li>
              <li>
                   <label>Comments</label>
                  :<span id="votes"> </span></li>

           </ul>
     </div> 

     </apex:repeat> 
  </apex:pageBlock>
```

(By the way, your getter on aggregate list is now useless, it would probably be better to put it in a new method)